# Maven publish is not found on jitpack

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I'm not able to use maven-publish plugin, it says there isn't maven-publish plugin even when it is there, this is my build.gradle file

```
plugins {
id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '8.1.1'
id 'maven-publish'
id 'java'
}

artifact = 'databaseapi'
group = 'net.jakush'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

publishing {
publications {
    maven(MavenPublication) {
        groupId = group
        artifactId = artifact
        version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

        from components.java
        }
    }
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven {
    name = "papermc-repo"
    url = "https://repo.papermc.io/repository/maven-public/"
}
maven {
    name = "sonatype"
    url = "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/"
    }
}

dependencies {
compileOnly "io.papermc.paper:paper-api:1.20.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT"
implementation "com.zaxxer:HikariCP:5.0.1"
}

def targetJavaVersion = 17 
java {
    def javaVersion = JavaVersion.toVersion(targetJavaVersion)
    sourceCompatibility = javaVersion
    targetCompatibility = javaVersion
    if (JavaVersion.current() < javaVersion) {
        toolchain.languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(targetJavaVersion)
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
    if (targetJavaVersion >= 10 || JavaVersion.current().isJava10Compatible()) {
    options.release = targetJavaVersion
    }
}

processResources {
    def props = [version: version]
    inputs.properties props
    filteringCharset 'UTF-8'
    filesMatching('plugin.yml') {
        expand props
    }
}
```

and this is error jitpack shows:
⚠️   WARNING:
Gradle 'publishToMavenLocal' task not found. Please add the 'maven-publish' or 'maven' plugin.
See the documentation and examples: https://docs.jitpack.io

I was trying everything google found for me, but nothing worked.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You should put needed information in the question rather than links. Also those links show an empty file to me. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I did not uploaded any images and also I tried to provide minimal reproducible example, but still I thought, whole file will be better. Instead of saying how to ask, if you would be great, you can help me with issue!

Comment: Whatever those "pastes.dev" links are, they don't work for me, or apparently for anyone else.  If they don't work, we can't answer.  You need to figure out how to copy and paste the text into the question.

Comment: Thats what I needed to hear, thanks. Fixed, now code is in question

Comment: @Jakush, did you figure out the solution?